# Como carregar vários registros dentro de um Combo?

Tags: javascript, java, html, json

Preciso criar uma funcionalidade para um sistema que a pessoa pode selecionar vários registros em um Combo, mas o problema é que estou carregando mais de 5000 registros e o browser está travando.

Existe alguma forma de criar isso sem travar? Tipo um autocomplete com a possibilidade de selecionar vários registros?

As informações estão vindo de um JSON.

Exemplo do que estou usando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Recomendo que você filtre no banco de dados para pegar os 20 primeiros utilizando LIKE, para que não ocorra o travamento do Javascript e para sua aplicação possuir uma performance melhor. Da para aproveitar aquele campo Filter.

Comment: Carlos podes colocar o código que tens? HTML e/ou JavaScript?

Comment: Acho que ele quis dizer que, toda vez que voce da um scroll para baixo ele gera +20 registros até acabar(tipo max(ou limit) e offset).

Comment: @CarlosPereira você usa Asp.net?

Comment: Isso mesmo @fsi, poderia ser assim também para não consumir muito a aplicação.

Comment: @Marconi, estou utilizando Java

Comment: @CarlosPereira Coloquei a tag do Java na sua pergunta, é bom você identificar qual eah a linguagem que você usa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar algo assim

```
$('#selectID').bind('scroll', function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight()>=$(this)[0].scrollHeight){
        // sua chamada ajax. e dando sucesso, voce adiciona um ".html(data)" no ultimo item do seu select
        // ou utiliza o json aqui e faz a logica
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Qual a necessidade de uma lista de 5.000 opções ?!

Não há como dividir o peso desta carga ?

JSON costuma ser rápido e fácil de lidar, então a melhor alternativa é dividir realmente esta exibição.